# Add Content to Search Index Based on Calculation of Properties in Record Center

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, calculated-column, records-center, indexed-column

I have a requirement to be able to search a record(document) in the record center based on a calculation. I can not store the calculated value as part of the item properties because an update of the property would constitute a change the item that is now immutable. Is it possible to leverage Content Enrichment or some other method to add to the index?

**Example:**

A record has a date (RecordDate) and text field (RecordText). I need to be able to search, filter, and refine on the condition that the date is greater than or equal to today OR the text field contains a specific value "ABC".

**Solution:** 
A radio button search refiner (Active, Inactive, All).  All is the default and adds nothing to the search filter. Active adds a filter of `(RecordDate>={Today} OR RecordText="ABC")` and Inactive adds filter `(RecordDate<{Today} AND RecordText<>"ABC")`.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 or 2016 this is not difficult. Lets assume that your date field is "RecordDate" and the text field is "RecordText". If you create a managed property of the same name for each you should be able to use the query `RecordDate>={Today} OR RecordText="ABC"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are correct that this effectively achieves the search result. I forgot to clarify that we would like to be able to refine/filter on the true or false evaluation result of (RecordDate>={Today} OR RecordText="ABC") in a search screen. This is where I am struggling.

Comment: I don't understand. Though you can write a custom refiner to work any way you like.

Comment: I guess this is exactly what i am asking. If a custom refiner is the solution how do I create one that evaluates 2 columns. My desired end result is an (Active, Inactive, All) radio button where Active adds a filter of (RecordDate>={Today} OR RecordText="ABC") and Inactive adds filter (RecordDate<{Today} AND RecordText<>"ABC") and All removes the filter.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried to do that.

Comment: I posted the solution I used, would love your input.

Answer (score 0):

This was accomplished by creating a custom refiner. The code used was:

The supporting JavaScript file (My_Filter_InactiveActive_functions.js) was

```
function applyActiveInactiveRefiner(val, refinementCtrl, refinerName, strQuery){    
var refiners = {};
refiners[refinerName] = null;
refinementCtrl.updateRefiners( refiners );
if (val == 1){ // Active 
    strRefinerValue = 'not(' + strQuery + ')';
    refiners[refinerName] = [strRefinerValue];
}
else if (val == 2) // Inactive
    refiners[refinerName] = [strQuery];
refinementCtrl.updateRefiners(refiners, 'or', false, null);

}
```

The refiner code file (My_Filter_InactiveActive.html) was

     
    
    `My Refiner - Inactive / Active Status`

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:CompatibleManagedProperties msdt:dt="string"></mso:CompatibleManagedProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:CompatibleSearchDataTypes msdt:dt="string"></mso:CompatibleSearchDataTypes>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string"></mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106604</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#Refinement;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
```

$includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/display templates/filters/EDF_Filter_InactiveActive_functions.js");

```
   <div id="InactiveActiveStatusRefinement">
<!--#_
  // Needed objects
  var listData = ctx.ListData;
  var hasControl = true;

  // Create a new hidden block outside the current refinement control
  var refElm = document.getElementById('Refinement');
  var hiddenBlockID = ctx.RefinementControl.containerId + "_" + ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName;
  var hiddenBlock = document.getElementById(hiddenBlockID);
  // Check if the hidden block exists, otherwise we create one
  if (hiddenBlock === null || hiddenBlock.lenght <= 0) {
    hiddenBlock = document.createElement('div');
    refElm.appendChild(hiddenBlock);
    hiddenBlock.setAttribute('id', hiddenBlockID);
    hiddenBlock.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
  }

  var currentRefinementCategory = ctx.ClientControl.getCurrentRefinementCategory(ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName);
  // Check if the object is null or undefined && Count the tokens currently in place
  var hasAnyFiltertokens = (!Srch.U.n(currentRefinementCategory) && currentRefinementCategory.get_tokenCount() > 0);
  var numFiltertokens = 0;
  if(!Srch.U.n(currentRefinementCategory))
    numFiltertokens = currentRefinementCategory.get_tokenCount();

  // Check if the current Refinement Control can be exists
  if ($isNull(ctx.RefinementControl) || $isNull(ctx.ClientControl)) hasControl = false;

  if (hasControl) {
    if(!$isNull(listData) && !$isEmptyArray(listData)) {
        // Show the refinement title
        var isExpanded = Srch.Refinement.getExpanded(ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName);
        var iconClass = (isExpanded == "true"? "ms-ref-uparrow" : "ms-ref-downarrow");
        var refinerCatTitle = Srch.Refinement.getRefinementTitle(ctx.RefinementControl);
        // Display style > needed to hide the refinement list when collapsed
        var displayStyle = (isExpanded == "true"? "" : "none");
        var today = new Date();

        var strQuery = 'and(' + ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName + ':range(min, '+ today.toISOString() +'),RecordText:not(&quot;No Expiration&quot;))'
_#-->
        <div id='Container'>
            _#= Srch.U.collapsibleRefinerTitle(ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName, ctx.ClientControl.get_id(), refinerCatTitle, iconClass) =#_
         <select class="ms-ref-unselSec" id="InactiveActiveStatusDdl" onchange="javascript:applyActiveInactiveRefiner(this.value, $getClientControl(this), '_#= ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName =#_', '_#= strQuery =#_ ');">

<!--#_
strHash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
strSelected = 'All';
  if(strHash.indexOf(ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName +'","t":["not(') > 0){
    strSelected = 'Active';
  }  
  else if(strHash.indexOf(ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName +'","t":[') > 0){
    strSelected = 'Inactive';
  }

  addRefiner(0, 'All', strSelected=='All');
  addRefiner(1, 'Active', strSelected=='Active');
  addRefiner(2, 'Inactive', strSelected=='Inactive');
_#-->
         </select>
      </div>

    <div id="RemoveRefinement">
<!--#_

    if(strSelected != 'All'){
        var refinerRemoval = new Object();
        refinerRemoval[ctx.RefinementControl.propertyName] = null;
        ShowRefiner('Remove refinement', null, refinerRemoval, 'updateRefinersJSON', false);
    }
_#-->
    </div>
<!--#_
    }
  } 
   function addRefiner(val, text, selected) {
      if (selected) {
_#--> 
         <option selected="selected" value="_#= val =#_">_#= text =#_</option>
<!--#_  
      } else {
_#-->  
         <option value="_#= val =#_">_#= text =#_</option>
<!--#_ 
      }
   }

   function ShowRefiner(refinementName, refinementCount, refiners, method, selected) {
        // Create the onClick or onChange event
        var onChangeOrClick = "$getClientControl(document.getElementById('"+ctx.RefinementControl.containerId+"'))." + method + "('" + $scriptEncode(Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(refiners)) + "');";

        // Check if there aren't filter tokens in place
        if (!hasAnyFiltertokens) {
            var elm = document.getElementById(hiddenBlockID);
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            var text = document.createTextNode(refinementName);
            option.appendChild(text);
            option.setAttribute('value', onChangeOrClick);
            elm.appendChild(option);
        }

        // Check if the refinement contains results && if the current item is selected
        if (refinementCount != null && selected !== true) {
_#-->
           <option value='_#= onChangeOrClick =#_'>_#= $htmlEncode(refinementName) =#_</option>
<!--#_
        } else if (refinementCount != null && selected === true) {
_#-->
           <option value='_#= onChangeOrClick =#_' selected='selected'>_#= $htmlEncode(refinementName) =#_</option>
<!--#_
        } else {
_#-->
            <div><a href='javascript:{}' onclick='_#= onChangeOrClick =#_'>_#= $htmlEncode(refinementName) =#_</a></div>
<!--#_
        }
    }


_#-->  
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```